# Force directed graph with circular group levels

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a graph that looks like the one on the image, which has circular levels. On these levels are placed all nodes, which are connected to each other (it does not matter how far they are from each other). Is it possible to do something like this in d3.js? (If not, do you know about any way (library?) that can do this?) I was thinking about creating a central node and making link to every node from it with fixed length, but I could not find a way how to do that. Thank you.

I have this set of nodes and links:

```
{
    "nodes":[
        {"name":"N1","group":0},
        {"name":"N2","group":0},
        {"name":"N3","group":1},
        {"name":"N4","group":1},
        {"name":"N5","group":1},
        {"name":"N6","group":2},
        {"name":"N7","group":2},
        {"name":"N8","group":2},
        {"name":"N9","group":2},
        {"name":"N10","group":2},
        {"name":"N11","group":3},
        {"name":"N12","group":3},
        {"name":"N13","group":4}
    ],
    "links":[
        {"source":0,"target":4},
        {"source":4,"target":2},
        {"source":2,"target":1},
        {"source":1,"target":6},
        {"source":6,"target":3},
        {"source":3,"target":8},
        {"source":8,"target":9},
        {"source":7,"target":5},
        {"source":5,"target":10}
    ]
}
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 2):

Use `d3.forceRadial()`. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#forceRadial), it...

> Creates a new positioning force towards a circle of the specified radius centered at ⟨x,y⟩.

In your case, for instance, setting a distance of 50 pixels from the center (defined as `width/2, height/2`) for each level:

```
.force("radial", d3.forceRadial().radius(function(d) {
        return d.group * 50
    }).x(width / 2)
    .y(height / 2))
```

Here is a very basic demo using your data:

```js
var data = {
  "nodes": [{
    "name": "N1",
    "group": 0
  }, {
    "name": "N2",
    "group": 0
  }, {
    "name": "N3",
    "group": 1
  }, {
    "name": "N4",
    "group": 1
  }, {
    "name": "N5",
    "group": 1
  }, {
    "name": "N6",
    "group": 2
  }, {
    "name": "N7",
    "group": 2
  }, {
    "name": "N8",
    "group": 2
  }, {
    "name": "N9",
    "group": 2
  }, {
    "name": "N10",
    "group": 2
  }, {
    "name": "N11",
    "group": 3
  }, {
    "name": "N12",
    "group": 3
  }, {
    "name": "N13",
    "group": 4
  }],
  "links": [{
    "source": 0,
    "target": 4
  }, {
    "source": 4,
    "target": 2
  }, {
    "source": 2,
    "target": 1
  }, {
    "source": 1,
    "target": 6
  }, {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 3
  }, {
    "source": 3,
    "target": 8
  }, {
    "source": 8,
    "target": 9
  }, {
    "source": 7,
    "target": 5
  }, {
    "source": 5,
    "target": 10
  }]
};


var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height");

var circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(5))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return width / 2
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return height / 2
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d * 50
  })
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "#bbb")

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink())
  .force("radial", d3.forceRadial().radius(function(d) {
    return d.group * 50
  }).x(width / 2).y(height / 2).strength(1))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody(-100));

var link = svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(data.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)
  .attr("stroke", "#444")

var node = svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(data.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("fill", "teal");

var text = svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(data.nodes)
  .enter().append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name
  })
  .style("font-size", "10px")

simulation
  .nodes(data.nodes)
  .on("tick", ticked);

simulation.force("link")
  .links(data.links);

function ticked() {
  link
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  node
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });

  text
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x + 8;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: node N7 is not on the second circle, how to solve this issue?